IntegrityError: Duplicate entry for primary key when inserting into MySQL table using SQLAlchemy and PyMySQL
classes
class ExamSchedule(db.Model):
    exam_time_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('exam_time.id'), nullable=False,primary_key=True)
    doctor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('doctor.id'), nullable=False,primary_key=True)
    date = Column(Date, nullable=False,primary_key=True)
    is_book = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)
    exam_registration_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('exam_registration.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False,unique=True)

class ExamTime(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_time = Column(db.Time, nullable=False)
    end_time = Column(db.Time, nullable=False)
    exam_dates = db.relationship('ExamSchedule', backref='exam_time', lazy = True)

class ExamRegistration(db.Model): 
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, )
    symptom = Column(String(255), nullable = True)
    exam_schedule = relationship("ExamSchedule", backref="exam_registration", uselist=False)
    patient_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('patient.id'),nullable = False)
    doctor_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('doctor.id'),nullable = False)
    is_waiting = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    doctor = relationship("Doctor", backref="exam_registrations")

class User(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    last_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    first_name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    gender = Column(String(50))
    birth_day = Column(Date)
    email = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    image = Column(String(255), nullable=True)

    phone_numbers = relationship(
        'PhoneNumber',
        backref='user',
        cascade='all, delete-orphan',  
        lazy=True
    )
    
    account_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False, unique=True)
    role = Column(String(50), nullable=False, default="user")  # Thêm trường role
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'user',  # Loại mặc định
        'polymorphic_on': role          # Dựa vào `role` để phân biệt vai trò
    }
    

class Doctor(User):
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True)
    specialty = Column(String(100), nullable=True) 
    degree = Column(String(100), nullable=True)  
    experience = Column(String(100),nullable=True)
    current_workplace = Column(String(100),nullable=True)
    exam_dates = relationship('ExamSchedule', backref='doctor', lazy=True)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'doctor',  
    }


file ulrs
@login_required
def confirm_appoint():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not current_user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect(url_for('auth.user_login'))
        else:
            doctor_id = request.form.get('doctor_id')
            exam_time_id =request.form.get('exam_time_id')
            symptom = str(request.form.get('symptom'))
            exam_day = datetime.strptime(request.form.get('exam_day'),  "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date()
            if not check_existing_schedule(exam_time_id,doctor_id,exam_day):
                exam_registration = add_apointment(symptom=symptom, doctor_id=doctor_id, patient_id=current_user.user.id)
                add_exam_scheduled(exam_time_id,doctor_id,exam_day, exam_registration.id)
            return redirect(url_for('appointment.appointment_main'))

def add_apointment(symptom, doctor_id, patient_id):
    new_exam_registration = ExamRegistration(
        symptom=symptom,
        doctor_id=doctor_id,
        patient_id=patient_id,
    )
    db.session.add(new_exam_registration)
    db.session.commit()
    return new_exam_registration

def add_exam_scheduled(exam_time_id,doctor_id,date, exam_registration_id):
   
    new_exam_scheduled = ExamSchedule(
        exam_time_id=exam_time_id,
        doctor_id=doctor_id,
        date=date,
        is_book=True,
        exam_registration_id=exam_registration_id
    )
    db.session.add(new_exam_scheduled)
    db.session.commit()
def check_existing_schedule(exam_time_id,doctor_id,date):
    existing_schedule = db.session.query(ExamSchedule).filter_by(exam_time_id=exam_time_id, doctor_id=doctor_id, date=date).first()
    if existing_schedule:
        return True
    else:
        return False


input data:
1: exam_time_id=1, doctor_id=6, date = 2024-11-25
2: exam_time_id=1, doctor_id=6, date = 2024-11-26
errors: (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry '1-6' for key 'exam_schedule.PRIMARY'") [SQL: INSERT INTO exam_schedule (exam_time_id, doctor_id, date, is_book, exam_registration_id) VALUES (%(exam_time_id)s, %(doctor_id)s, %(date)s, %(is_book)s, %(exam_registration_id)s)] [parameters: {'exam_time_id': '1', 'doctor_id': '6', 'date': datetime.date(2024, 11, 26), 'is_book': 1, 'exam_registration_id': 38}] (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/gkpj)
Why are there 3 fields as primary key but why does it report duplicate error?
I want to know why it gives an error even though the date field entered a different value, and how to fix it

When you originally created the ExamSchedule model, did it only have time_id and doctor_id as primary keys, and then you added date as a third primary key later?

yes............

Then that is the reason.  After creating the model, changing the python model definition won't automatically update the actual database table definition.  Either you have to drop the table and re-create it, or you have to do a schema migration.

it worked, thank you
